# Rotate view iPhone tabbar app

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation

I have an app with a mainwindow which contains a tabbar controller and a number of different views. I want the whole thing to be able to rotate in each direction, however doing

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

didn't help, while that did work in other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITabBarController` requires that you enable rotation on all view controllers it manages.  So each view controller should return YES for that method for the orientations you wish to rotate to.

Comment: I did just that, i've got 3 buttons with a view for each, return YES for each view, and still no rotating.

Comment: Make sure you have the same code in the UITabBarController's implementation file, as well as all the child viewcontrollers' implementation files.  Also you can check out this tech note for more ideas:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html

Comment: I found out that I had added a uiview to my app, and that was the reason it stopped rotating, it doesn't matter if i return yes for shouldautorotate in that view.m, it refuses to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted each view to rotate, you have to return `YES` on each view in the tab bar controller as well.