# Minimum steps to get autorotate to work

Tags: objective-c, ios, autorotate

I've trying to implement autorotate but my app is not listening to me!

The app has a tab bar controller which supervises 3 view controllers.  The tab bar is created programatically in the app delegate.  **Each** of the view controllers has this standard simple method:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

The app delegate looks like this:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:gameVC, settingsVC, helpVC, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

In addition, in the target summary area I have all 4 orientations for both the iPad and iPhone activated.

In the simulator, no rotation occurs with either device.  I seem to be missing something.  Perhaps one more setting is needed?  Something out of order?  There is nothing else in the project related to rotating views.

Comment: Which ones? I don't see anything in there that applies.

Comment: which iOS version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zack @AlexanderZats This was subtle.  I was reading this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748545/rotate-view-iphone-tabbar-app) which brought me [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html)  This 2nd link is a great discussion of different possible reasons an app may not rotate.  The last point caught my attention.  Sure enough, I was overriding `initWithNibName` and not calling `super` on it.  I think this ultimately meant that the the VCs were not in the responder chain.  A huge thanks to all who gave me ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you seemed to not have said in your response that I can think of is changing the device orientations under your info.plist. I know from personal experience that if you click on the supported device orientations in the target summary area, it might not actually change it in the Info property list. Check and make sure that all four are selected in the property list by doing the following:

- Go to your Info.plist
- Look under Supported interface orientations and Supported interface orientations (iPad)
- Make sure that it has 4 strings under both: Portrait (bottom home button), Portrait (top home button), Landscape (left home button), Landscape (right home button)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that setting.  Alas, they are there complete and correct.

Comment: From other questions here I determined that each VC must be requesting the exact same behavior or they are all ignored.  So that is how I set it up: all 3 VCs have the same code.  Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @BryanHanson add this into your code `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"Is Portrait");
    }
    
    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"Is Landscape");
    }
    
    return  YES;
}`

Do this to see if it is even recognizing the rotation.

Comment: This is interesting.  I put your code into one of the 3 VCs, the one that is in front at start up.  It reports "Is portrait" 3x during launch.  Then when I rotate it neither rotates nor logs any msgs.  Does this give you something to go on?

Comment: This actually is telling us that it is not responding or realizing that it is flipping to rotation which could be your problem. When I type this in to my project, It pops up in Portrait at startup x2 and then when I put it to landscape mode it says it Is Landscape x2 and flip it again returns it back to Is Portrait and so on and so forth. For your tab bar project, did you use the template?

Comment: I did not; the project evolved along an odd trajectory.  I eventually did create a sample project with a tab bar controller and have used it extensively to guide my project.  I'm going to study it's plist and project settings to see if I have missed something.  EDIT: Looks the same for all orientation related parameters.

Comment: Yeah you have me stumped. Everything if you said you're doing correct should be making the view rotate. Tell me if you come up with anything!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have 2 tab bar items, to account for the log showing up 2x?

Comment: This was actually not done in a tab bar application rather just the one project I had opened up at the moment. However, I created a project with tab bar and it doesn't seem to be communicated like I thought it would with a regular application.

Comment: UPDATE: I have learned that you actually MAKE SURE that each view controller has return YES; with tab bar because if one does not then it will not rotate that way for any of the views i.e. upside down was not allowed in view 2 but return yes was on view 1. View 1 would not rotate upside down

Comment: Right.  See 2nd comment above.

Answer (score 1):

User a ViewController for super purpose, and then inheritance it in the each of view controllers. In the super ViewController add this

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
  return YES;
  }

So, you just need to do once to make them autorotate

Answer (score 0):

from  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW26

> Tab bar controllers support a portrait orientation by default and do
>   not rotate to a landscape orientation unless all of the contained view
>   controllers support such an orientation. When a device orientation
>   change occurs, the tab bar controller queries its array of view
>   controllers. If any one of them does not support the orientation, the
>   tab bar controller does not change its orientation.

Comment: @AlexandarZats Thank you.  I am aware of this issue, and all three VCs have the same autorotate code so they should respond in unison so to speak, and all support all orientations.

Comment: Also Apple significantly changed rotation logic in iOS6, which one do you use in your tests?

Comment: you code and approach looks completely legitimate, try subscribing for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` just to make sure it "happens" on the level of simulator / device, don't really see any issues with your code, besides try creating a test setup with just one "simple" `UIViewController`. It always helps me to start debugging the issue from the point where everything works

Comment: @AlexandarZats Good strategy.  Implemented.  The device **does** know it is changing.  Is there something that can be set in the nib to block rotation?

Comment: not really, prior iOS6 every presented view controller would decide for itself (except for cases such as `UITabBarController`, `UINavigationController`) by responding to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`. But what you have here is a really peculiar case, if you can isolate it down to barebones (e.g. just three view controllers that cause the issue) I would love to take a look at the code